# How write get sum of array with mapReduce MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given following database schema:

```
{
    '_id': 5079,
    'name': 'Lincoln County', 
    'state': 'AR',
     'population': 13024,
    'cases': [{'date': '2020-03-16', 'count': 1}, {'date': '2020-03-22', 'count': 1}, 
              {'date': '2020-03-24', 'count': 1}, {'date': '2020-03-26', 'count': 2}], 
    'deaths': [{'date': '2020-03-27', 'count': 1}, {'date': '2020-04-02', 'count': 1}, 
               {'date': '2020-05-28', 'count': 2}, {'date': '2020-05-30', 'count': 1}] 
}
```

What MongoDB mapReduce function would generate a collection of the total number of covid19 case counts for each states. Generate one record for each state with its 2-letter abbreviation and its total covid cases?

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried to achieve the result, it will allow the community to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "total": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$cases",
            "as": "c",
            "in": "$$c.count"
          }
        }
      },
      "state": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SrPodf5SPnf)

The query uses `$map` to create an array with values from `cases.count` and then `$sum` these values.
Also, the fields ouput are `count` which contains the `$sum` and the state using `state: 1`.